# Customizer doesn't recognise sidebar

Tags: sidebar, theme-customizer

I have registered a sidebar and I use it on all of my pages. For some reason the customizer doesn't recognise it.

Have I done something wrong?

Here's my code:

**functions.php**

```
function registerSidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Main sidebar',
        'id' => 'main-sidebar',
        'description' => 'Main sidebar on the left.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget flex-column %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h5 class="widgettitle font-weight-bold">',
        'after_title' => '</h5>'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'registerSidebar' );
```

**sidebar.php**

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'main-sidebar' );
```

Then I just include my sidebar in the **header.php** file, like this:

```
get_sidebar();
```

Here's an image of the message I get:

[image: problem]

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

I were using jQuery in the wrong way, which made the customizer fail.

*This is how you should enqueue a script with jQuery:*

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-great-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

See more on [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/) page.